# .htaccess file for wordpress example.com/blog redirecting to example.com

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

My website at `www.tripfelt.com` uses the `.htaccess` below to handle pretty URLs:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

# enable rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^robots.txt - [L]
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?/ [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

`www.tripfelt.com/blog` uses the following `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

However, clicking on any blog item, instead of opening the blog story, is redirecting to the main site. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

Blog folder

```
  # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /blog/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

  # END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the base in your `blog` folder to `/blog/` and remove the leading slash in the routing rule:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```